# Why/how does this work: Symfony 2.8 + FOSRestBundle automatically deserializes request object

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I am working on migrating an existing `Symfony 2.8` which I did not create. The previous developers are not available for questions.

Most of the code easy to understand, but at one point I simply cannot figure out how are why this works:

A controller/action parameter is automatically de-serialized from `JSON` data to a custom object. This is nothing special, I do not understand how/where the Symfony is told what to do. Form my point of view important config data is missing but it works anyway.

**That's would be fine, but without understanding why it works in this case, I cannot figure out why it does not work anymore when migrating the project to `Symfony 3.4`...**

Sorry for the (very) long question, but I tried different ways to solve the problem and answer the questions but they all resulted in different problems...

Using the following Bundles

```
sensio/framework-extra-bundle       v3.0.29
friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle        2.4.0
jms/serializer                      1.13.0 
jms/serializer-bundle               1.5.0
```

Config:

```
// app/config/config.yml
sensio_framework_extra:
    request: { converters: true }

fos_rest:
    ...
    body_converter:
        enabled: true

#jms_serializer:  (not configured)
#    ...
```

Code:

```
// src/AppBundle/Util/SortInfo.php
class SortInfo {
    public $sortOrder;
    public $sortBy;
}


// src/AppBundle/Resources/serializer/Util.SortInfo.yml
AppBundle\Util\SortInfo:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        sortOrder:
            type: string
            expose: true
        sortBy:
            type: string
            expose: true

// src/AppBundle/Controller/SortingController.php
class SortingController extends Controller {
    ...

    /**
     * @FOSRest\View()
     */
    public function sortAction(SortInfo $sortInfo) {
        $this->logger->info("sortAction");
        $this->logger->info("   ".gettype($sortInfo)."  --  ".get_class($sortInfo));
        $this->logger->info("   ".$sortInfo->sortOrder."  --  ".$sortInfo->sortBy);

        ...
    }     
}
```

**That's it.** After digging for some hours I could not find any explicit configuration that would tell the `sortAction` method to convert the `JSON` data from the request automatically. **But it works.**

A request with the following `JSON` content results in the following log output:

```
// JSON content
{"sortOrder":"ASC", "sortBy":"name"}

// Log output
sortAction
    object  --  AppBundle\Util\SortInfo
    ASC  --  name
```

**Why does this work?**

As said before this is fine, but the problem is, that the same code does not work with `Symfony 3.4` and newer versions of FOSRest, ExtrasBundle and JMSSerializer:

```
sensio/framework-extra-bundle       v5.2.4
friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle        2.5.0
jms/serializer                      2.1.0
jms/serializer-bundle               3.0.0
```

A request with the same `JSON` data results in the following log output in `Symfony 3.4':

```
// Log output
sortAction
    object  --  AppBundle\Util\SortInfo
      --
```

So although the `SortInfo` is created (not null), the `sortBy` and `sortOrder` properties are empty/null.

How can this be? I do not understand why the data is de-serialized in the first place, but how it is possible to create a `SortInfo` object without setting the properties is even more mysterious.

In `Symfony 2.8` the `Util.SortInfo.yml` file is necessary for the process. Removing this files results in an exception:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException: "You
>   must define a type for
>   AppBundle\Util\SortInfo::$sortBy."
>
> at /.../vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/Request/**RequestBodyParamConverter.php**

Here I do not understand why `SortInfo::$sortBy` is a problem but not `SortInfo` it self. Additionally removing the file in `Symfony 3.4` does not change anything.

But at least this error message confirms, that the FOS `RequestBodyParamConverter` is involved in the process.

Following the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/request_body_converter_listener.html) it should be necessary to manually specify that the parameter that should be converted (although it works just fine without this config in `Symfony 2.8`):

```
/**
 * @FOSRest\View()
 * @ParamConverter("sortInfo", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
 */
public function sortAction(SortInfo $sortInfo) {
    ...
}
```

However, adding this config results in another error in `Symfony 3.4`:

> Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Converter
>   'fos_rest.request_body' does not support conversion of parameter
>   '$sortInfo'

Bottom line:

- This is all very mysterious.
- Why does it work without any problem in `Symfony 2.8` although regarding to the docs essential config is missing (explicitly specify ParamConverter)
- Why does it NOT work in Symfony 3.4?

Comment: HI ! You have to develop a custom ParamConverter to make it work on SF > 3 : https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter

Comment: I know that one can create custom ParamConverters but are you sure this necessary? In fact the project uses other class which (for some reason) explicitly sets `@ParamConverter("sortInfo", converter="fos_rest.request_body")` (no custom converter) and just works fine both in SF 2.8 **and** SF 3.4 (this is just another mystery but I did not what to make the question even longer...)

Comment: "app/console debug:container --tag=request.param_converter" might offer a clue.  It should list all the available param converters.  Not sure if it will work under 2.8 though.